(Primevue) Function to stop horizontal scrollbar from moving when clicking on a Dropdown
There is a code within my system that makes the scrollbar reposition itself if a dropdown is clicked on a minimized window (click on a dropdown that's only halfway visible and this code readjusts there automatically).
What I need to do is that I am trying to make a function inside the Primevue dropdown where I am trying to prevent what is happening above.
Code:
<script>
import Dropdown from 'primevue/dropdown'

const onDropdownClick = () => {
  const scrollPosition = window.scrollX
  setTimeout(() => {
   window.scrollTo(scrollPosition, window.scrollY)
}, 0)
}
</script>
<Dropdown
   v-model="value"
   :options="options"
   :name="props.name"
   :placeholder="placeholder"
   :editable="editable"
   :disabled="disabled"
   :option-label="props.ol"
   :option-value="props.ov"
   @update:model-value="onDropdownClick()"
   @click="onDropdownClick()"
/>

The above ALMOST works. The horizontal scrollbar does not move when a dropdown is clicked. However there is a small window where it tries to move then goes back, creating a quick back and forth effect. I am trying to adjust my const onDropdownClick to stop this.
Something else that I tried is:
const onDropdownClick = () => {
   const scrollPosition = 0
   window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
   window.scrollTo(scrollPosition, 0)
})
}

somehow the code above stops the horizontal scroll from moving even if I am not clicking the dropdown.
Any other ways my const onDropdownClick can be adjusted? Trying not to modify my initial code where the scrollbar auto adjusts on click as it may affect other parts of my system. Any help would be appreciated.
